# Apache2 starting, then port fails to bind

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, ssh

I have centOS 6.4 64bit and apache2 (httpd) installed. I do:

```
 /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

And Apache starts up fine with just a green [Ok]

However; when I try to load any webpages hosted on it they fail to load and:

```
service https status
```

Shows that https is stopped.

When using:

```
service httpd restart
```

I get this error:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

What could be causing apache to do this?

Comment: What happens when you reboot the machine? That is the very first thing you should do in a case like this to see if that clears things up.

Comment: When you see that error run `netstat -nap | grep '0.0.0.0:80'`.  Look at the far right column which will contain the PID/process that is bound.  I've seen this happen when doing a restart sometimes.  You may have better luck doing `service httpd stop;sleep 1;service httpd start`

Comment: The `-l` option is handy in this situation as `netstat` then only lists listening ports.  Also you must run it as root for the `-p`option to work.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    netstat -antu|grep 80
    lsof -i -n -P|grep 80
```

try with with [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609130/quick-way-to-find-if-a-port-is-open-on-linux)

or [NixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/)

Comment: Apache seems to be using a iPv6 address that is taking port 80, can I have some help and fixing/removing that function of it so it only uses iPv4? httpd     10975  root    4u  IPv6 1010994      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)

Answer (score -1):

You probably have a line in your httpd.conf that looks like:

```
Listen 80
```

try changing it to:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

which will make it listen on all IPv4 addresses.  Recent apaches will listen to (only) IPv6 by default if you just have Listen 80 , if the system has as valid IPv6 address (even just a link local self-assigned address).

Comment: Don't the messages about not being able to bind to [::]:80 and 0.0.0.0:80 kind of imply that it can't bind to any IPv6 or IPv4 address ?